# PHP Ordering Results taken from Facebook Public Search

Tags: php

When I search like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=silvio+berlusconi&type=post&limit=10&since=1328263810&until=1328436610
```

Facebook returns the correct values..But it is returning the newest ones previously and then the older ones...

How do I do the opposite.

I think that if I search for SINCE and then UNTIL it would be logic to give me before the older ones and then the newer ones...but Facebook does not have any logic as I see so far... :(

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) to pass-in your query including an ORDER BY clause.